# Using VBA function to check colomn has NA error and create an IF-Then Else output

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA function but getting an error , can someone take a look and suggest where I am going wrong.

What the function is doing is looking at Column 1 and checking if its error then assigning value of No to X. Same with Y on a different column.

If either of them have a value or name then the output is Yes, else its a No

Added picture, I am getting a value error  right now. But if column F and G are same column H is a yes, if either one has a name H is yes. Only when both are N/A H is a No.

```
Function Checkmapping(x As Variant, y As Variant)

If x = "#N/A" Then
    x = "No"
End If

If y = "#N/A" Then
    y = "No"
End If

If x <> y Then

Checkmapping = "Yes"
    Else: Checkmaping = "No"

End If


End Function
```

[image]

Calling via

[image]

BigBen: I know the formula is easy, but want a VBA function , just so I can add more complex logic later, if there are 10 parameters the formula will get crazy.

Comment: How are you going to be using this function? Why not use `WorksheetFunction.IsNA`? Feels like you're recreating the wheel, since this could be done with regular Excel formulas.

Comment: mis-spelled Checkmapping the second time as Checkmaping, put Option Explicit at the top and it won't compile like that.  If you truly want to change the value of x and y that are passed into your function, be sure to call it out by using ByRef in front of those variables.  There is not enough code there to tell us if changing x and y will have the behavior that you want, as we can not see the write to address offset portion of your code.  You also do not appear to define what you are returning the function as, apparently it is As String . . . How are you calling the function?

Comment: "I know the formula is easy, but want a VBA function, just so I can add more complex logic later" - got it. Why not then give us the 10 parameters in this question? Otherwise, the answers you get - i.e. what @Chris Neilsen has provided - may not necessarily be easily expandable to those 10 parameters... But it looks like you got what you're looking for - so great!

Comment: Thanks Chris !!! you the man !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several issues here:

- A cell containing an `#N/A` error is not the same as a cell containing the text "#N/A"
- If a cell contains an error value (including `#N/A` comparing it to a string in VBA will throw a run-time error
- There is a typo: `Checkmaping = "No"` vs `Checkmapping = "No"`

Refactored code

```
Function Checkmapping(x As Variant, y As Variant)
    If Application.IsNA(x) Then
        x = "No"
    End If
    If Application.IsNA(y) Then
        y = "No"
    End If
    If x <> y Then
        Checkmapping = "Yes"
    Else
        Checkmapping = "No"
    End If
End Function
```

Based on your statement *Only when both are N/A H is a No.* the above won't give that result.  Then try this

```
Function Checkmapping(x As Variant, y As Variant)
    Checkmapping = "Yes"
    If Application.IsNA(x) Then
        If Application.IsNA(y) Then
            Checkmapping = "No"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Bonus: based on your comment *I know the formula is easy, but want a VBA function , just so I can add more complex logic later, if there are 10 parameters the formula will get crazy.*

```
Function Checkmapping(r As Range)
    Dim cl As Range
    Checkmapping = "No"
    For Each cl In r
        If Not Application.IsNA(cl) Then
            Checkmapping = "Yes"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Call it like `=Checkmapping(F10:G10)` or `=Checkmapping(F10:Z10)` to check more cells

And just for completeness, you *can* do this with a Formula for a variable number of cells

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(F10:G10,-1)+1),"Yes","No")
```

Enter as an Array Formula (complete with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and then copy down